# Custom Post Type doesn't use single.php or single-{custom_post_type}.php

Tags: posts, customization

I tried to set up a custom post type in Wordpress, and everything worked just fine.

Until displaying a single post from my custom post type.
First it didn't automatically use the `single.php` (as it should), and then I tried to create a custom `single-{custom_post_type}.php` but it doesn't even use that one :/

I'm kind of confused now.

**//Edit:**

Solved the problem. Just had to add `flush_rewrite_rules();` after register post type in functions.php

```
register_post_type( 'communitydeals' , $args );
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

Comment: You should do that only once, and then remove it. `flush_rewrite_rules()` are expensive to run on every page load

Comment: You even shouldn't use `flush_rewrite_rules()` in your theme, it is not in theme scope, You can write and small plugin and use this code `add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'flush_rewrite_rules' );` to flush rewrite rule for custom post type only when you change theme . Or only updating permalink structure once from Admin Menu >> Settings >> Permalinks will make it work fine there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. Just had to add `flush_rewrite_rules();` after register post type in `functions.php`:

```
register_post_type( 'communitydeals' , $args );
flush_rewrite_rules();
```

Comment: You don't want to call `flush_rewrite_rules()` on every page load!

Answer (score 0):

First Didn't did you create custom post type page?

Example i have a custom post type called compute i will create a file called  compute.php and single-compute.php  and write your code for  multiple posts in compute.php and single post in single-compute.php  if you still not showing or showing file not found try to logout your site and delete browser history and open in another browser try to login hope this would help :-)